# How to handle a bib source with no author?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, german, author, english

I am writing a paper in English and have a couple of sources that have no author. In German there would be the abbreviation `o.V.` standing for `ohne Verfasser` which translates to `no author` in those cases.

How is this handled in English papers? Would an appropriate translation be `n.a.` standing for `no author`? Is there a way in Latex to automatically put something in place by just providing a bib entry without an author?

Instead of:

```
@online{cloud-ide04,
    author = {n.a.},
    title = {codeanywhere},
    publisher = {Codeanywhere, Inc.},
    urldate = {2018-03-26},
    url = {https://codeanywhere.com/}
}
```

Rather do:

```
@online{cloud-ide04,
    title = {codeanywhere},
    publisher = {Codeanywhere, Inc.},
    urldate = {2018-03-26},
    url = {https://codeanywhere.com/}
}
```

Comment: This all depends on the bibliography style (and to a much lesser extend the bibliography package: `natbib`, `biblatex`, ...) you use. If you give no authors, many styles will just try to move on without an author. Other styles can not handle entries without author and will throw an error or give garbage output.

Comment: You may have better luck asking for the expected output with missing authors on https://academia.stackexchange.com/: But they will probably answer that it depends on your style guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question 'How is this handled in English papers?' is probably better suited for [Academia.se](https://academia.stackexchange.com/). I expect that the takeaway message from an answer would be: Check with your style guide/supervisor.

The impact of a missing author is different for different styles. While author-year systems need an alternative way to generate the citation label if the author is missing, numeric styles don't have this kind of problems. For styles that sort by name you have to find a way to sort entries without authors properly.

Apparently some style guides prefer to put "Anon." or "Anonymus" as author for sources without author (*Oxford Guide to Style*/*New Hart’s Rules*, cf. [`biblatex-oxref`'s `oxyear` documentation, p. 10](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-oxref/oxyear-doc.pdf)). But others just let a missing author go, even some author-year styles ([APA](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/05/missing-pieces.html), [Chicago Manual of Style](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/717/03/) and [MLA](https://style.mla.org/source-with-no-author/)). They just use the title in citations if necessary.

---

For BibTeX/`biblatex` the situation is similar: 'It depends on your style.'

The quick solution of putting `o.V.` or `n.A.` or `Anon.` as author if there is none could be seen as semantically unsound: You pretend that the author of a work is 'no/without author' (one might reply that 'no author' is a null object to avoid denotation failure here, but I'm not sure if that leads anywhere). It also has the obvious drawback that these strings are (generally) not automatically translated into other languages. But more importantly, if you put `author = {Anon.},` you will have trouble getting the correct output with citation styles like APA that simply leave out the author if there is none. If done incorrectly, this approach can also have other quirks. `author = {ohne Verfasser}` will make BibTeX think a guy with family name 'Verfasser' and given name 'ohne' wrote the book. If names are inverted ('Knuth, Donald E.') in the bibliography you will end up with 'Verfasser, ohne' - probably not what you want. So you would have to use at least `author = {{ohne Verfasser}},` Then you will also have a hard time to convince BibTeX or `biblatex` to write 'o.V.' in citations.

So in general I would prefer not giving the author field if there is no author. That way the style has full control over what to do: Most will probably just ignore that and get on with the title. Not all styles can handle missing authors gracefully, though. On the other hand, it is entirely conceivable that a style automatically substitutes 'o.V.' or 'Anon.' for the missing author in case cases. I don't know of a style that automatically writes 'o.V.' if there is no author, but the following code could do that for `biblatex`

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[notfield=translator, final]
      \step[notfield=editor, final]
      \step[fieldset=author, fieldvalue={{{o\noexpand\adddot V\noexpand\adddot}}}]
    }
  }
}
```

Other more stable methods are possible, but they will depend on the exact style used.

---

Generally, I would always try to find an author even if it seems like there is none. It is normally considered acceptable to use corporate authors, so

```
@online{cloud-ide04,
  title       = {codeanywhere},
  author      = {{Codeanywhere, Inc.}},
  shortauthor = {Codeanywhere},
  urldate     = {2018-03-26},
  url         = {https://codeanywhere.com/}
}
```

would be a good alternative for your example.

Comment: For reference: The Academia.SE question is at https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/108463